# Sending multiple messages socket c

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, message

I am writing this post because I have a problem with my C socket. When I send messages very quickly in a loop from the server to the clients, the client displays all the messages in one string and I don't know why. However, when I send a message followed by a sleep, I do not have this problem. Would it be possible to have an explanation please?

Serveur code without sleep:

```
int nombreDeJoueurs = joueurs + robots;
int taille;
for(i = 1; i<= nombreDeJoueurs; i++){
    sprintf(saisie,"Le joueur %d a %d têtes de boeufs", i, vie[i]);
    for (j = 1; j <= joueurs; j++){
        taille = write(pollfds[j].fd,saisie,strlen(saisie));
    }
}
```

Output client :

> Le joueur 1 a 1 têtes de boeufsLe joueur 2 a 0 têtes de boeufsLe joueur 3 a 0 têtes de boeufsLe joueur 4 a 0 têtes de boeufs

Serveur code with sleep:

```
int nombreDeJoueurs = joueurs + robots;
int taille;
for(i = 1; i<= nombreDeJoueurs; i++){
    sprintf(saisie,"Le joueur %d a %d têtes de boeufs", i, vie[i]);
    for (j = 1; j <= joueurs; j++){
        taille = write(pollfds[j].fd,saisie,strlen(saisie));
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Output client

> Le joueur 1 a 1 têtes de boeufs

> Le joueur 2 a 0 têtes de boeufs

> Le joueur 3 a 0 têtes de boeufs

> Le joueur 4 a 0 têtes de boeufs

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74556434/boost-server-breaking-the-messages-from-the-client

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption, that you would send multiple messages is wrong.

From [man write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html):

> write() writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at buf to the file referred to by the file descriptor fd.

To be more specifically: all you're doing is to write a number of bytes into the underlying stream. The number of calls of the function `write` does not determine the number of 'messages'.

If the socket buffer is full, the socket implementation will flush the remaining bytes and send them over the network to the client. If you wait too long, the socket implementation will automatically flush the buffer in certain time intervals.

That's why your sleep version works. But it is the wrong approach. You have to implement a protocol between the server and client. An example would be to send the length of the message (either as text or binary), so that the client would first read the length and then read only that much from the stream to form a message (string).